# Not having to create an infinite amount of onClickListeners

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

So I'm working on an app that has a numerical button pad. Of course something has to happen when a button is pressed, so I have to have an onClickListener for each button right? The problem is that I have 40 buttons in landscape mode so then I would have to create 40 different onClickListeners. I figure there must be a better way to do this. Do any of you have any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by two-way,

**I.**

Declare and define your buttons;

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
```

Invoke buttons-

```
button1.setOnClickListener(menuButtonListener);
button2.setOnClickListener(menuButtonListener);
button3.setOnClickListener(menuButtonListener);
```

Implement button listener, define jobs for different button inside switch case

```
private OnClickListener myButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
      switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1 : // do your job
        case R.id.button2 : // do your job
        case R.id.button3 : // do your job
   .....
       }
     }
}
```

**II.**

Set your layout xml using the `android:onclick` attribute-

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

Then in your activity class add the `onClick` method.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.button1 : // do your job
    case R.id.button2 : // do your job
    case R.id.button3 : // do your job
...
 }
}
```

Comment: I really like the second approach. It requires the least code I think. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is for sure a better approach.. You just create a single onClickListener and set it to them all. You can put any information as the view's tag by calling `view.setTag(Object)`.
And in your onClickListener you can do `view.getTag()` returning the same object. 
Hope it was helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

Implement onClickListener in you activity. Then in your button do like this:-

```
Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
b1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

then

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.bttn1:
        //do something
        break;
    case R.id.bttn2:
        //do something
        break;
    case R.id.bttn3:
        //do something
        break;
            .
            .
            .
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create only one onClickListener and set same for all the buttons. Whenever button is clicked, onclick method of onClickListener is called and is having view as a parameter. From view use getId method to identify which button is clicked and accordingly perform action. Some thing like this:

```
private OnClickListener onButtonlickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.id_1:
            // TODO: Your Code for id_1
                break;
            case R.id.id_2:
            // TODO: Your Code for id_2
                break;
            case R.id.id_3:
            // TODO: Your Code for id_3
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }
    };
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can give them all the same onClickListener instance and then perform different actions depending on the View id that initiated the callback. So, in pseudo code -

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
     if(v.getId() == <someid>) {
       .. perform action
     else if (v.getId() == <someotherid>) {
       ..perform another action
      }
}
```

Or you could use a switch statement instead an if.

Answer (score 1):

Make your class implement onClickListener and override the onClick method.

```
bClearSearchAllSA.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v) 
{
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.clearSearchAllSA: 

        case R.id.followingSA:

        case R.id.followersSA:
    }
}
```